# How do you convert $(12.0251)_6$ into fractions?

Tags: number-systems, fractions

How do you convert $(12.0251)_6$ (in base 6) into fractions?

I know how to convert a fraction into base $x$ by constantly multiplying the fraction by $x$ and simplifying, but I'm not sure how to go the other way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you want decimal notation in your fraction. We have
$$(12.0251)_6=(1\times 6^1) + (2\times 6^0) +\frac{0}{6^1}+\frac{2}{6^2}+\frac{5}{6^3}+\frac{1}{6^4}.$$

Bring the right-hand side to the common denominator $6^4$, and calculate.  Equivalently, multiply by $6$ often enough that you get an integer $N$ ($4$ times) and divide by that power of $6$.  After a while, we get that $N=10471$. Since $6^4=1296$,
$$(12.0251)_6=\frac{10471}{1296}.$$

**Another way:** Note that $(12.0251)_6=\dfrac{(120251)_6}{(10000)_6}$. Convert numerator and 
denominator to base $10$. This looks slicker, but the computational details are the same.

**Comment:** There is a nice trick for making the calculation of the numerator easier. It goes back almost two thousand years in China, and is sometimes called *Horner's Method*, after an early 19th century British schoolmaster.  We work from the left. Calculate in turn

$(1\times 6)+2=a$

$(a\times 6)+0=b$

$(b\times 6)+2=c$

$(c\times 6)+5=d$

$(d\times 6)+1=e$

Our numerator is $e$. We find that $e=10471$.

Horner's Method does not really speed up things in this small calculation.  But with longer calculations, there is substantial gain. Horner's Method is a useful tool when we want to evaluate a high degree polynomial $P(x)=a_0x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+ \cdots +a_n$ at a particular numerical value of $x$. With a bit of practice, it is even a handy tool for evaluation of polynomials with a calculator. There is no need to ever "store" intermediate results.

Comment: Thanks, but why is the first term 6?

Comment: @Arvin: $(12.0251)_6= 6^1 \times 1 + 6^0 \times 1 + 6^{-1} \times 0 + 6^{-2} \times 0 +\cdots+ 6^{-4} \times 1$.

Comment: What about if the 0251 part is repeating? as in, the questions is $(12.\overline{0251})_6$

Comment: For repeating, note that $(.0251)_6=\frac{103}{6^4}$. So the repeating part is the infinite geometric series $(103/6^4)(1+1/6^4+1/6^8+\cdots)$. The inner sum is $1/(6^4-1)$.

Comment: Note that for some people, Horner's method is more familiarly known as "synthetic division", as dividing a polynomial in $x$ by $x-a$ and evaluating that same polynomial at $x=a$ are equivalent tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use continued fractions.

```
                       Cf     A   /  B
             12.0251           1  /  0      In the left, we produce a 
    1.0000  -12.0000    8      8  /  1      continued fraction from 
   -0.5420    0.0251   12     97  / 12      12.0521 and 1.0000, in base 6
    0.0140   -0.0140    1    105  / 13        There are Cf of the positive 
   -0.0111    0.0111    1    202  / 25      number, which gives the negative
    0.0025   -0.0054    2    511  / 63      number.
   -0.0013    0.0013    1    713  / 88        The right is Cf(r-1) + Cf(r-2)
              &c                            starting at 1 in A and 0,1 in B.
```

You stop when the error gets precise enough, or you get a zero in either column.